# Does Ubuntu App Showdown Allow Inventive Games?

Tags: application-development

Yes, I have an idea I have been toying around with for a game for a long time. But just haven't had a real reason to get it going. Til the Showdown was announced that is.

Its a very out of the ordinary RPG style game. I'm not a programmer so I would be using Illumination Software Creator to make it. Most likely with the help of the Lunduke forum, and attribution given where needed.

But I need to first know if my entry would even be accepted? I plan to have the Load, Save, and New game options, as well as other interesting ones that may come to mind, as the Quicklist requirements.

So the only question is, do innovative games scratch an itch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely, feel free to submit innovative games!

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but would you know of any good write ups on how to integrate an app into the Quicklists? Preferably for beginners, as I am still very new at learning python. Thank you for anything you can come up with. :-D